# TextBox value that was set by JQuery is not avaliable in serverside page load event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have set a textbox value by calling a jQuery function .The textox value is assigned perfectly but it is not on server side .it is showing empty. This is my script side code.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" AccessibleHeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" MaxLength="5" ValidationGroup="a" BorderStyle="Solid" Text='<%#Eval("QTY") %>'
                                                                                            Width="50px" BorderColor="#CCCCFF" onkeypress="return AllowNumbersOnly(this,event)" AutoPostBack='false' 
                                                                                            OnChange="javascript:totalCalc();" Height="12px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="50px" BackColor="#A8AEBD"/>
                                                                                    <ItemStyle Width="50px" Height="12px" />
                                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">
                                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblRate" runat="server" DataField="RATE" Text='<%#Eval("RATE") %>'
                                                                                            ItemStyle-CssClass="price" Height="12px" />
                                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbltxttotal" runat="server" Text="Total: "  Font-Bold="True" />
                                                                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" BackColor="#A8AEBD" />
                                                                                    <ItemStyle Width="100px" Height="12px" />
                                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

### Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=txtQuantity]").val("0");
    });
    $("[id*=txtQuantity]").live("change", function () {
        if (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
            $(this).val('0');
        } else {
            $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()).toString());
        }
    });
    $("[id*=txtQuantity]").live("keyup", function () {
        if (!jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                var smt = parseFloat($("[id*=lblRate]", row).html()) * parseFloat($(this).val());
                var hid = (parseFloat($("[id*=lblRate]", row).html()) * parseFloat($(this).val())).toFixed(2);
                $("input[id*='txtAmount']", row).val(hid);

            }
        } else {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("input[id*='txtAmount']", row).val("0");
            $(this).val('');
        }

        var total = 0.00;
        $("#gv1 input[id $= 'txtAmount']").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            total = parseFloat(total) + Math.round(parseFloat(value));
        });
        $("#txtTotalAmount").val(total);
        $("#lblTotal").val(total);

    });
</script>
```

---

on server side

```
 drow[0]["TOTAL"] = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAmount")).Text);

((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAmount")).Text return empty
```

Comment: How about formatting your code so it's easy to read?

Comment: Please format the question better. It's really hard to read and there seem to be missing code.

Answer (score 2):

The value changed by client side scripting language like *javascript* is not available in server side as Server Side uses `ViewState` to get the value of form controls. You can use a `hidden` field assign the value to it in *javascript* and get the `hidden` field on server side.

*Html*

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdn" runat="server" />
```

*JavaScript*

```
document.getElementById("hdn").value = "your value";
```

*Code behind*

```
string hdnValue = hdn.Value;
```

Comment: Or you could try turning off the viewstate for that control?

Comment: I need to get textbox value in each row of  grid in loop . please check my code and script.

Comment: @Adil ViewStateMode="Disabled"